# .NET 7.0 set culture for inputTagHelper in type Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datetime, razor

I'm running an ASP.NET Core 7.0 web app with Razor and I can't find a way to change localization in input tag helper for type date.

How can I switch this text to Spanish?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What exactly you would like to implement? What date type you are searching to change? date format or whole calender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1: Add the following codes in ***Program.cs*** file to use Spanish culture:

```
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo("es-ES"),
};
options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("es-ES");
options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});

var app = builder.Build();

var localizationOptions = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions.Value);
```

Step2: Set Spanish as your browser's default language.

Step3: In Razor page, use the ***asp-format*** attribute to format the date using the appropriate format string for the Spanish culture. Here is the code of my test razor page:

```
@page
@model TestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DateOfBirth"></label>
        <input asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="form-control" type="date" asp-format="{0:d}" />
    <span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

@*<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>*@
```

and here is the code of the ***Test.cshtml.cs***:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WorkRazor.Pages
{
    public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<PrivacyModel> _logger;

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public TestModel(ILogger<PrivacyModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
}
```

Here is my test result:
[image]

Comment: Step 2 its the key. Thx a lot